# What meaning does the parameter have for UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>.alloc()?

Tags: pointers, swift, generics

Let's say I want to create a *pointer* to an `Int` in Swift. From what I've seen I'd do [this](http://swiftstub.com/766736251/):

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)
pointer.memory = 100
println(pointer)        //prints 0x00007f8672fb7eb0
println(pointer.memory) //prints 100
```

Now, when I call `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)`, what does `1` denote? I assume its the number of `Int`s allocated in memory starting from the pointer adress.
So `1` would allocate *8 bytes*, `2` would allocate *16 bytes*, and so on...
Is this true?

If so, how much memory does Swift allocate for `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>`s using a *generic* type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, when I call `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)`, what does 1
>   denote? I assume its the number of Ints allocated in memory starting
>   from the pointer address.

It is the number of items for which memory is allocated.

> So 1 would allocate 8 bytes, 2 would allocate 16 bytes, and so on...
>   Is this true?

Almost. One `Int` can be 4 or 8 byte, depending on the
architecture.

> If so, how much memory does Swift allocate for
>   `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` using a generic type?

You cannot allocate memory for a generic type. At the point where
`alloc()` is called, the type parameter `T` must be known, either given
explicitly or inferred from the context.